# ¿Cómo realizar un reemplazo de valores de una lista de equivalencias en otra hojas usando VBA en lugar de BUSCARV?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

Tengo una lista de códigos que necesito reemplazarlas por sus equivalentes en una lista de una siguiente hoja donde los valores que no estén en la hoja de equivalencias salga la celda como vacío.
Normalmente estoy se puede hacer usando BUSCARV con SI.ERROR y luego se copia y pega el resultado. Sin embargo, al querer hacerlo en VBA me gustaría saber alguna idea para poder armarlo. Muchas gracias por su ayuda e ideas.

Lista a Homologar

[image: Lista a homologar]

Lista de Equivalencias en la siguiente hoja

[image: Lista de equivalencias]

Resultado final con códigos cambiados al correr la macro y con celdas vacías al no encontrar su equivalente.

[image: Resultado Final]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te pongo un ejemplo para que lo adaptes a tus necesidades. Siguiendo estas tablas de mi ejemplo el código que te pongo carga las dos tablas en diccionarios y devuelve los valores buscados en la columna F:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Sub CruzaDatos()

    Dim dicc1 As Object, dicc2 As Object
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
            
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    'Creo diccionarios. Uno para cada lista.
    Set dicc1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dicc2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    'Guardo la lista COD-PROD
    For i = 2 To 6
        If Not dicc1.exists(CLng(sht.Cells(i, 1))) Then dicc1.Add CLng(sht.Cells(i, 1)), sht.Cells(i, 2)
    Next
    'Guardo la lista COD-CLAVE
    For i = 2 To 6
        If Not dicc2.exists(CStr(sht.Cells(i, 5))) Then dicc2.Add CStr(sht.Cells(i, 5)), sht.Cells(i, 4)
    Next
    'Cruce de datos
    For i = 2 To 6
        If dicc2.exists(CStr(sht.Cells(i, 5))) Then sht.Cells(i, 6) = dicc1(CLng(dicc2(CStr(sht.Cells(i, 5)))))
    Next
    
    Set dicc1 = Nothing
    Set dicc2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Un saludo.